# Open a PDF directly into users PDF application from database

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

I have created an application using JavaFX.  I have a PDF being uploaded into the Database as its designed to be viewed at a later date and aiming to make this portable (DB and files hosted on a Server).

At the moment my code extracts the bytes from the database stored in a LongBLOB and writes this to a file on the D:\ drive.

This is then opened up using the user's default PDF application.

Is there away of opening this in directly without writing to a file first?  Do not want users to have to download the file before it can be viewed.

**Here is the view PDF code:**

```
public void viewPdf(ActionEvent event) throws IOException, SQLException {
    byte[] pdf;
    Controller control = new Controller();
    Connection con = control.connectDB();
    PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT pdf, filename FROM files WHERE pdf_id =?");
    statement.setInt(1, pdfId);

    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
    if (rs.next()) {
        pdf = rs.getBytes("pdf");
        filename = rs.getString("filename");
        OutputStream newFile = new FileOutputStream("D:/pdfs/" + filename);
        newFile.write(fileBytes);
        newFile.close();

    }
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("D:/pdfs/" + filename));
    statement.close();
    con.close();
}
```

Comment: what you're doing is what most browser PDF plugins / PDF web-readers do, they write the PDF file to a temporary location and launch off the reader.

Comment: @AhmedMasud would it be feasible to delete the file after it has been read, therefore when they close the file (application) it will require writing again?  or is it more feasible to keep future in mind and put path in the DB instead as the files will be hosted on an FTP server?

Comment: It depends on the use-case, if the files are frequently accessed by the reader are static and don't change content over a long period of time then leave them there (offline first is a good user experience). Your plan to host the files on a remote server addresses all caching.  Highly advisable to use an SSL web server for it. As it supports per-user authentication/permissions as well as provides a robust user-experience for the foreseeable future. OTH FTP tends to be fraught with security perils and should be avoided, also FTP has no 'mime-types' support, which opposes your OP design spec.